# LWJGL Determining the location of a 3D object on screen

Tags: 3d, 2d, computational-geometry, trigonometry, lwjgl

Quick question (maybe so).  Is it possible to efficiently calculate the (x,y) location of 3D vertices?  For example, I have a cube which is 1x1x1 in size and lies at the origin (0,0,0).  While it is on screen, what would the on-screen coordinates of each of the cube's 8 vertices?

Comment: See I told you matrices were useful. I suggest you actually take the plunge and accept using matrices is easier. Then look up homogenous coordinates it really is beneficial no matter what you say. All your problems hinge on this point. Thing is most 3d engines build upon these concepts all other sources will be using matrices as their main calculation platform. Thus all explanations are in matrix form. Matrices are after all our primary mathematical tool for solving linear systems on computers efficiently.

Comment: Hahaha! I knew you would come back to get me on that.  I've already given in to the vectors and matrices, and I must admit, you were right :P

Comment: Then my work is done :) let me know if you need some pointers. Remember this same calculation solves your furstrum problem.

Comment: Thanks and yes I finally got that working as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Just matrix multiply your 3d vectors with the view matrix and in case of perspective projection divide by the homogenous coordinate. See Wikipedia on [3D projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection), for the mathematical details. Which also provides a decomposition of the matrix so you dont need to deal with matrices if you wish.